# Macro to pick Excel Save As location based on cell value is giving runtime error 1004

Tags: excel, vba

Here is my code

```
Public Sub SaveAsA1()

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
.InitialFileName = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("R1").Value
.Show
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=Range("R1") & ".xlsm", FileFormat:=52

End With
 MsgBox "File Saved!"
End Sub
```

but when I choose a location it does not over-write the cell value and it give a runtime error #1004.

Please can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

You've got two possible issues that I can see:

1. You're getting a file name with the `FileDialog` method, but then
   using whatever is in the cell as your `SaveAs` name, regardless of
   what the user just picked.
2. You might be double-appending the file-name based on what is already in the cell.

Here's a suggested fix to your code to set the cell contents of `"R1"` to the value the user chose before saving the file:

```
Public Sub SaveAsA1()

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
    .InitialFileName = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("R1").Value
    .Show
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("R1").Value = Trim(.SelectedItems(1))
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("R1").Value, FileFormat:=52
End With

MsgBox "File Saved!"
End Sub
```